# How do the Planar Shepherd's features interact with the Outlands?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron, prestige-class, planes

I have recently read up on the Planar Shepherd, and I have a few questions about it regarding its interaction with the Outlands. And while I know the Planar Shepherd is in an Eberron book, and as such has nothing to do with the Great Wheel... well, when did that stop anyone?

One of its class features, Planar Attunement, lets you attune to a plane matching your alignment and not suffer the negative effects on it. The Outlands have their thing with that magic stops working the closer you get to the Spire, eventually probhibiting all casting. In a similar way, if you go beyond that circle of influence (1200+ miles or so), either spacetime begins to unravel or you keep the same distance away from the spire, no matter how far you walk. First question: does Planar Alignment cancel out these effects?

Second, at 9th level Planar Shepherd allows you to Wild Shape into an elemental/outsider native to that plane. What exactly constitutes as a native to the Outlands? I imagine that the inhabitants of the Border Towns count as living in the Outlands, giving you access to a LOT of creatures to Wild Shape into, from Archons to Slaadi to Demodands and from Modrons to Eladrin to Baatezu. And of course beings like the Concordant Killers, who gather in the Outlands but travel the Planes. So what counts as being native to the Outlands?

Finally, how do the Planar Bubble and Intensify Manifest Zone interact with the Outlands? Do you get zones that impede casting, or is it a patch of regular ground?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a RAW answer, or an answer of how we'd run it in our games?

Comment: Three things, really: RAW, from the POV of a player and from the POV of the DM.

Comment: That... doesn't really clarify it.  I'm not asking about what point of view you want, I'm asking whether house rules or homebrew content would answer your question or not.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. There's no homebrew answer to this: it's more of a hypothetical situation.

Comment: If a prestige class was all that was necessary to avoid the magic-cancelling affect of the Outlands, the Gods would surely be immune, too - But they're not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some planar shepherd questions won't generate good answers when the questions are about the class's abilities' interactions with planes outside the Eberron campaign setting. Even the planar shepherd's own Adaptation section is unhelpful, saying, for example, "If manifest zones do not exist in your campaign, the 10th-level ability to create one could instead allow creation of a planar touchstone (*Planar Handbook* 153)" (*FE* 109). That ability to create apparently *permanent* manifest zones was, I assume, excised in editing. Thus, as always, ask the DM when considering using such classes in campaign settings other than home ones.

## Questions & Answers

The planar shepherd (*FE* 105-9) is largely considered one of the most powerful prestige classes in the game. When a *druid* takes a prestige class, it *must* be good.

- ***Question:*** Does the planar shepherd's extraordinary ability planar attunement render the shepherd immune to the normal magic, impeded magic, and limited magic traits that occur the closer he gets to the Outlands' central spire?

  ***Answer:*** No. The planar attunement extraordinary ability reads

  > At 1st level, you must choose a single plane of existence other than the Material Plane.... Once selected, your planar shepherd features are forever attuned to this plane. You cannot choose a plane with an alignment trait opposed to any component of your own alignment. [...] You and your animal companion ignore any harmful effects derived from your chosen plane's elemental or energy traits, as well as any natural environmental affects
  >   associated with the plane. [...] You are also immune to the entrapping effects of planes .... If you choose, you can share this benefit with a number of allies equal to your class level; these allies must remain within 100 feet of you to gain this benefit.
  >
  > **This immunity does not extend to the plane’s** physical traits (including gravity and time), alignment traits, or **magic traits**.

  Emphasis mine.
- ***Q:*** What creatures are the Outlands' natives for the purposes of the planar shepherd's supernatural ability wild shape?

  ***A:*** Not many. The planar shepherd's supernatural ability wild shape reads

  > Your druid levels stack with your planar shepherd class levels for the purpose of determining the number of daily uses, the maximum HD and size (but not creature type), and the duration of your wild shape ability.
  >
  > At 3rd level, you are able to use wild shape to change into a **magical beast** native to your chosen plane, with the same size restrictions as for animal forms. [...] **This includes creatures whose type changes to magical beast as the result of applying a
  >   template (such as celestial or fiendish).**
  >
  > When you attain 9th level, you become able to use wild shape to change into an **elemental or outsider** native to your chosen plane, although it costs two of your daily uses of wild shape to do so. [...] In addition to the normal effects of wild shape, you gain all the elemental or outsider’s extraordinary, supernatural, and spell-like abilities.

  Unlike some other planes, no *template* exists to make, for example, animals into magical beasts by making them more Outlandish. Worse, while the outlands is home to countless creatures because of its position on the Great Wheel, few published creatures are *native* to the Outlands.<sup>1</sup> Even residents from other planes who've lived there a long time--or were even born there--*still* aren't *native* to the Outlands. *Dungeons and Dragons*'s immigration policy is *horrible* that way; there are very few ways to *make* oneself native to plane if one's race is from another plane; such creatures are usually unique.

  Finally, the elemental or outsider forms into which the planar shepherd can wild shape remain restricted by the druid's wild shape which is, in turn, restricted by the special ability [alternate form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm), which reads, "A creature cannot use alternate form to take the form of a creature with a template." Thus the planar shepherd could not, for example, use his wild shape ability to assume the form of *any* creature *via* the template petitioner (*MP* 199-200).

  What remains, then, are printed creatures like the following:

  - The concordant killers (*MM4* 34-5) are outsiders native to the Outlands.
  - Illurien (*MM5* 90-1) is a unique being who resides in the Outlands; if she's native is the DM's decision.
  - The kuldurath (*FF* 116) is a Large 9 HD magical beast native to the Outlands.
  - The rilmani (*FF* 140-3) are the iconic outsiders native to the Outlands.<sup>2</sup>
  - The simpathetic (*Dragon* #351 52) is a Tiny 1 HD magical beast native to the Outlands.<sup>3</sup>

  Undoubtedly other creatures exist in more obscure sources.
- ***Q:*** What does the the supernatural ability planar bubble and the spell-like ability *intensify manifest zone* do when the planar shepherd's picked the Outlands?

  ***A:*** For the supernatural ability planar bubble, not much. The special ability reads

  > Beginning at 5th level, once per day you can create an area around yourself that emulates the environment of your chosen plane. This area mimics all traits of your chosen plane, including physical traits, elemental and energy traits, alignment traits, and magic traits. This area has a 20-foot radius and lasts as long as you concentrate (up to a maximum of 1 hour per level) plus 1d10 rounds. At 10th level, you can use this ability three times per day.

  The outlands has the following traits according to the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2013)

  - *Divinely morphic.* This trait disappears close to the center of the plane, and in that area even deities are affected by the nature of the plane.
  - *Mildly neutral-aligned.* Unlike on the other Outer Planes, all alignments are equally welcome on the Outlands.
  - *Normal magic, impeded magic, and limited magic.* The Outlands has the normal magic trait far from its central spire, but as one approaches the hub of the plane, spells, spell-like abilities, and even supernatural powers are further and further restricted. Where the surface of the plinth is near vertical, almost no abilities (and few deity-level powers) function. Far from the spire, magic functions normally.

  The only interesting trait is the last, but as that trait's dependent on proximity to the spire, it has no effect. Nonetheless sometimes it's worthwhile to have the ability to create a safe zone when planar traits are otherwise dangerous.

  For the spell-like ability intensify manifest zone, it's unclear what happens when the Outlands is picked. The ability will likely have an effect similar to one of those created by an *orrery of the planes* (*ECS* 271), but the DM must determine what effects--if any--occur.

---

1. Seriously, a player who picks the Outlands for his planar shepherd should encourage the DM to create or adapt more.
2. The rilmani got a raw deal in *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition*. While never *more* popular than *any* other minor iconic (there were more *3rd Edition* [yugoloths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoloths) than rilmani but an equal number of [demodands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demodand)), they're nonetheless important planarly... planally... *to the planes* and [received a lot more attention in *Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition*.](http://www.lomion.de/cmm/rilmani.php) A fan's conversion of *2nd Edition* rilmani to *3rd Edition* is [here](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?10060-The-Rilmani-Champions-of-Neutrality-%28conversion%29), and more about the rilmani can be learned from [*Timaresh: The Mirrored Library*](http://www.rilmani.org/timaresh/Main_Page), a Web site taking its name from a rilmani institution. The Web is a *strange* place.
3. The article containing the creature is Todd Stewart's "The Gatetown of Ecstasy," likely of interest to one considering a trip to the Outlands.

Comment: Alright, I understand #1 and #3. #2 though... I get that you would not get the Outland Petitioner template (And given that it grants immunity to Polymorph, I think that as a shapeshifter you do not even WANT that), but being a native does not automatically grant you the petitioner template (see: Planar Shepherd 10), nor does having the template cause you to be a native. So would it be possible to Wild Shape into a native WITHOUT the petitioner template?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs If the DM rules that in his campaign certain *kinds* of creatures are native to the plane the planar shepherd has chosen, then the DM *should* let the planar shepherd wild shape into them. It's also up to the DM if a planar shepherd can wild shape into, for example, *an elemental native to the Outlands* or if the shepherd's wild shape must abide by the *typical* creature's native plane. Finally, the shepherd's still restricted by familiarity, so the DM may rule that while weird shapes are possible, the shepherd's just *unfamiliar* with outsiders who are atypical natives.

Comment: Alright. But what about this: "In addition, petitioners that seem more native to other Outer Planes sometimes walk the Outlands(...)Or maybe these petitioners were not quite good or evil enough to truly merit their inclusion on an aligned plane." (MotP 148). This suggeests that while they SEEM native to other Planes they are not, and are in fact native to the Outlands because they are too Neutral to be on their "home" plane. Given that this information comes AFTER the detailing of the template, it is quite possible that these creatures do NOT have it, and as such are fair game for Wild Shape.

Comment: The section you're citing is headed *Outlands Petitioners.* Petitioners *have* the petitioner template. Lacking the petitioner template means the creature's not a petitioner. If you've a different question (e.g. "How can a druid wild shape into any outsiders?"), you should ask it.

Comment: I've done a bit more research, and I did find a type of native who does NOT have the Petitioner template: a 10th level Planar Shepherd native to that particular Plane. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

### Outlands

1. The only thing in Planar Attunment that might make you immune to the spell-removal, divine-removal and distance from spire thing is the 'immune to natural environmental traits of the plane' line.  'Environmental' is defined in the DMG.  It does NOT include 'gigantic spell removal Spires'.  Also the spell removal is not a listed planar trait.
2. Rilmani.  Metal-skinned humanoids, some of which are statted out in *Fiend Folio* (updated 3.5e).  'Native' is again a defined term, it means 'the plane you get Banished to by the Banishment spell'.  Example: If a Solar celestial, native to the Seven Mounting Heavens of Celestia, uses the *Plane Shift* spell to travel to Outlands, it is still Native to Celestia.  It does not become Native to Outlands.  This is true of any outsider that is present in Outlands.  Even if that Outsider changes it's alignment somehow (Spell or ability, or 'extreme circumstances'), it is still not native to Outlands.
3. Even if the Spell-Removal was a planar trait (it's not), it's based entirely on distance from the spire.  Even if you create a bubble of that plane, you're still not within distance from the spire - you're on a whole nother plane.  So, you just get basic outland traits, i.e. very boring nothin' doin'.

Me, i'd just houserule it.  I'd have the Planar Bubble treat YOU as sort of a mini-spire, stopping spells you didn't cast from happening of progressively higher levels in concentric rings around you.  As you leveled up, the levels of spells blocked would get higher, until within 5' of you the spells blocked were of the highest level you could cast -2, with every 10' away from you the level of spells being blocked dropping by 1 spell level.

Comment: Do not argue in the comments.  [Our rules](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) are quite clear on the issue, **be nice** and comments are for clarification.