# Is there a complete list detailing all Magical Beasts and Outsiders native to the Outer Planes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, prestige-class, planes

I am looking to write a guide on the interaction between the Planar Shepherd and the various Outer Planes, but for this I am looking for an overview of all Magical Beasts and Outsiders native to said planes. Thus far I have had no success with this: I have found a website (ending in .de, but it's in English and not posted here because of the iffy copyright issues) that says to contain some of them, but this one's far from complete. What I know so far is the following:

- Celestia: Archons
- Bytopia: ?
- Arcadia: Guardinials
- Beastlands: ?
- Arborea: Eladrin, Titans
- Ysgard: ?
- Limbo: Githzerai, Githyanki, Slaad, Xac-yji (Planar Handbook)
- Pandemonium: Windblade
- Abyss: Demons
- Carceri: Demodand
- Hades: Night Hag
- Gehenna: Yugoloth
- Baator: Devils
- Acheron: ?
- Mechanus: Inevitables, Formians, Modron
- Arcadia: Arcadian Avenger (MM V)
- Outlands: [See this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38209/how-do-the-planar-shepherds-features-interact-with-the-outlands?answertab=votes#tab-top); this is likely to be the complete list for the Outlands already.

Now, I am specifically looking for the creatures that are legal targets for the Planar Shepherd's Wild Shape ability. Does a list with these creatures exist somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A Planar Shepherd-specific List Is Probably Unavailable...

...but the Web site [*Oryan's RPG Locker*](http://www.rpglocker.com/) has in its [Downloads](http://www.rpglocker.com/index.php?file=c-downloads), in both Excel (which I haven't tried) and PDF formats, a document entitled ["Monsters and Gods Sorted by Planes."](http://www.rpglocker.com/DnD/D&D_3e_monsters_gods_by_plane_list.pdf) It's extensive, covering (but *not* reproducing) *Dungeons and Dragons 3.X* and *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition* material (and probably earlier material, too) and even referencing (but *not* reproducing) *Dragon* and *Dungeon* magazine material.

"Monsters and Gods Sorted by Planes" is just a big list of stuff and where to find it; any actual *details* about the list must be acquired by the user (the document doesn't even list creatures' Hit Dice), so it's the kind of fan-made thing that *should* be totally legit, but if this answer needs to be deleted because someone suspects the document of wrongdoing, so be it.

The document is obviously someone's labor of love, a project that must've taken *at least* months to complete. I want to put a name to this document so the fellow who made it can get credit, but I can't find one. I hope Comments can.

Comment: The PDF looks pretty good, though I'm sort of confused by its accuracy. For example it mentions that Titans (MM1 p. 242-243) can appear in Arcadia, which stokes with both its alignment (Chaotic) and its native area (Arborea). I have looked it up and the Titan does appear on the Heavenly Encounters table (MotP, p. 152, D% 87). But this would mean that the creatire in question is not native to Arcadia: instead it can just be encountered there. So would they be legal targets for the Planar Shepherd's Wild Shape?

Comment: Titans, then, likely wouldn't be eligible. Honestly, I don't think the list you *want* exists--i.e. a list of exclusively and definitively called-out-as-native creatures. Determining what creatures are native (for planar shepherd purposes) *without* DM input runs the risk of being deeply dissatisfied with only limited options. The document I linked to is a *starting point* for negotiations between you and the DM.